# Redraw only part of canvas - .net Maui

Tags: c#, .net, canvas, maui, draw

In my .net Maui application I want to draw a pulsating circle on a canvas. I've tried just invalidating the graphics view 15 times per second (as to achieve 15 FPS). As the canvas is much bigger than just this pulsating circle however, this approach is very laggy, which I understand.

Is there any way to only rewdraw the area where the circle is or to have it on a seperate layer and only redraw that?

Or is there any other way to have an animation like this on a canvas?

Drawable:

```cs
        public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
        {

            // Draw the image background.
            if (_image != null)
            {
                canvas.DrawImage(_image, Padding + _translationX, Padding + _translationY, _width, _height);
            }

            // Draw other stuff

            // Draw pulsating circle
            canvas.DrawCircle(_x, _y, _radius);
            canvas.FillColor = Colors.Red;
            canvas.FillCircle(_x, _y, _radius);

            var radiusStep = dirtyRect.Width / 15;

            _step++;
            if (_step > 15)
            {
                _step = 1;
            }

            canvas.DrawCircle(_x, _y, radiusStep * _step);
        }
```

Comment: More context and seeing the relevant code would be helpful. At the moment, you're not offering a lot of useful information.

Comment: Are you using .net maui graphics or skia?

Comment: @Julian I'm Sorry, I've added some code, if you need anything else, just tell me.

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro I'm just using .net maui graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Draw each circle once. Have the larger one in front. Instead of redrawing the circles, just toggle whether the larger circle is transparent or not.

Comment: Im not sure it is possible to change the visibility of drawn elements on a maui canvas. Do you have any documentation or example code regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

The canvas is wiped clean ever time you invalidate so it is up to your logic to repaint everything in that order you want it.

One way to do a pulsing object is to Start with a GraphicView. In that you put an animation to control the pulses.

```cs
internal async Task AnimateRippleEffect()
{
    float start = 0;
    float end = 1;

    _animationManager?.Add(new Microsoft.Maui.Animations.Animation(callback: (progress) =>
    {
        _drawable.AnimationPercent = start.Lerp(end, progress);
        Invalidate();
    }, duration: 0.4, easing: Easing.SinInOut,
    finished: () =>
    {
        _drawable.AnimationPercent = 0;
    }));

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

In your Drawable you put something like this

```cs
private double _animationPercent;

public double AnimationPercent
{
    get => _animationPercent;
    set => _animationPercent = value;
}
public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
{
    var center = new PointF((float)dirtyRect.Width / 2, (float)dirtyRect.Height / 2);
    
    canvas.SaveState();

    canvas.FillColor = Colors.Red.WithAlpha(0.75f * (1 - (float)_animationPercent));

    canvas.Alpha = 0.55f;

    float minimumRippleEffectSize = 0.0f;

    var rippleEffectSize = minimumRippleEffectSize.Lerp(dirtyRect.Width * 0.65f, _animationPercent);

    canvas.FillCircle((float)center.X, (float)center.Y, rippleEffectSize);

    canvas.RestoreState();
}
```

I have a pulsating/ripple effect in my **[repo](https://github.com/PeterWessberg/MAUISamples/blob/main/src/CustomControls/Drawables/RadioButtonDrawable.cs)** you can look through for a more complete code example. You will also find other ways to use MAUI Graphics for both 2D and 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Because the animation is just the last part, you can split your code over two GraphicsView with two Draw routines. The first GraphicsView is responsible for the background only. The second GraphicsView just focuses on the final animation.

Also, if you're just drawing circles and nothing else, you can consider Rectangle with RadiusX, RadiusY set, or BoxView with CornerRadius set.

```xml
<Grid WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200">
    <!-- Background -->
    <Image/>
    <Border Stroke="Orange"
            StrokeThickness="4"
            Background="Red">
        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <BoxView CornerRadius="100"/>
        </Border.StrokeShape>
        <ContentView/>
    </Border>
    <!-- Animate this using view model -->
    <Border Stroke="Orange"
            StrokeThickness="4"
            Background="Transparent"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="{Binding InnerWidth}"
            HeightRequest="{Binding InnerHeight}">
        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <BoxView CornerRadius="{Binding InnerRadius}"/>
        </Border.StrokeShape>
        <ContentView/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```